# Create a JAX-WS webservice without generating Binding Objects from XSD

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jaxb2

I have a bunch of Objects that are not annotated for JAX-WS and have XSD to go along with it. I am writing a Webservice Interface for them but do not wish to generate all of those JAX objects from XSD but rather like to use DynamicJAXBContext to create an bind objects at run time. My motivation is to keep a static memory footprint and also to use existing objects that are already available. I have about 100+ objects that are involved in the xsd and i dont want to duplicated object footprint for JAX. 
Option 
1) I am planning to use Logical Handler to intercept the JAX message and use Dynamic JAX Context to Marshal and unmarshal the payload.
2) Use Eclispe Moxy Libraries to wrap your JAX-WS

I am open to ideas. I can certainly try these out, wanted to make sure if i headed towards a stone wall, Hell if no response then i am bound to crash and learn from it. Any input is appreciated..

Comment: Have you actually analyzed your application to verify the memory footprint of the JAX-B objects, vis-a-vis the processing time it'll take to parse an object afresh on demand?

Comment: That is my concern as well. The memory footprint of the generated objects is quite high. I dont want to  maintain a bloated list of duplicate objects used for binding. I would like to reuse the existing ones for that. All i need is to maintain the sequence of elements marshalled conforming to the xsd. My XSD name elements are based on the beanSpec so it should be transparent to map to existing objects that i have. Xstream does this very nicely but does not respect XSD. JAB respects XSD but does not appear marshall transparently by default using xsd with no binding objects.